# Data source is an invalid type. It must be either an IListSource, IEnumerable, or IDataSource

Tags: c#, asp.net, data-binding, drop-down-menu

i have a function that get a DropDownList , should run a store procedure and get back a Supplires names taht should be displayes at the dropdownlsit .

This is the function :

```
public void LoadSuppliers(DropDownList ddl , int num)
{
    con = connect("igroup9_test1ConnectionString");
    using (SqlCommand sqlComm = new SqlCommand("[spGetSuppliers]", con))
    {
        if (con.State != ConnectionState.Open)
        {
            con.Open();
        }

        try
        {
            sqlComm.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            sqlComm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RowMeterialID ", num);

            sqlComm.CommandTimeout = 600;
            ddl.DataSource = sqlComm;
            sqlComm.ExecuteNonQuery();
            ddl.DataBind();
            ddl.DataTextField = "sName";
            ddl.DataValueField = "sName";
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw (ex);
        }
    }

}
```

And this is the procedure:

```
USE [igroup9_test1]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[spGetSuppliers]    Script Date: 03/24/2014 18:13:12 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER proc [dbo].[spGetSuppliers]
(
@RowMeterialID int
)

as

begin

select distinct sName
from Supplier, RawMaterials, SupplierRawMaterials
where RawMaterials.rmID=@RowMeterialID and RawMaterials.rmID=SupplierRawMaterials.rmID and SupplierRawMaterials.SupplierID=Supplier.SupplierID

end
```

When i'm running the program it throw an error:

> System.InvalidOperationException: Data source is an invalid type.  It
>   must be either an IListSource, IEnumerable, or IDataSource.

Comment: I think the error is rather clear.  You're assigning a data source that doesn't implement any of those interfaces, and it needs to for that to work.  What about it don't you understand?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot assign `ddl.DataSource = sqlComm` since it is a SqlCommand.

Fill a `DataSet` and assign

```
ddl.DataSource = dsMyResult;
```

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to assign the instance of `SqlCommand` directly to your `DataSource`:

```
ddl.DataSource = sqlComm;
```

I'm not sure if that's a typo or you thought it would automatically run the stored procedure and assign the results to the control, but it won't work.

Also, `ExecuteNonQuery()` isn't the correct method to call, if your looking to get records back. Try `ExecuteReader()` instead:

```
var reader = sqlComm.ExecuteReader();

while (reader.Read())
{
    // Do something with the data
}
```